# How to use CombinePDF with Rails 6 (ActiveStorage) on heroku

Tags: pdf-generation, ruby-on-rails-6, prawn, combine-pdf

I generate PDF documents using Prawn in Rails.  For years I have only inserted jpg's into PDFs.  More recently I've had a need to insert an external PDF into a Prawn PDF.  The way to do this seems to be to merge PDFs together using CombinePDF.

I have this functionality working successfully IF I use a local document.  As soon as ActiveStorage gets in the mix, it stops working...it times out.

- Rails -v 6.1.1
- Ruby -v 2.7.2p137
- Prawn -v 2.4
- CombinePDF -v 1.0.21
- on Heroku using Amazon S3

The test file I am using is only 50k in size.  The exact same thing occurs whether I attempt this in Development or Production (on heroku).  In the logs I can see:

```
S3 Storage (716.2ms) Downloaded file from key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

And, then ....

```
Request ran for longer than 28000ms
```

## Gemfile

gem "combine_pdf"

## PdfsController

```
    class PdfsController < ApplicationController
      require 'combine_pdf'
      require 'net/http'
      include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

      def the_report
        thing = Thing.find params[:thing_id]
        documents = Document.with_attached_attachments.where(id: thing.document_ids).joins(attachments_attachments: :blob).where(blob: {content_type: 'application/pdf'})
        respond_to do |format|
          format.pdf do
            prawn_pdf = TheReport.new(params[:thing_id]).render
            final_pdf = CombinePDF.new

            final_pdf << CombinePDF.parse(prawn_pdf)
            
            documents do |doc|
              doc.attachments.each do |attachment|
                # time out occurs here
                url = rails_blob_url(attachment, only_path: true)
                final_pdf << CombinePDF.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body)
              end
            end

            send_data final_pdf.to_pdf, filename: "thing.pdf", type: 'application/pdf', disposition: 'inline', compress: true, optimize_objects: true
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

The request at Net::HTTP.get_response seems to be taking too long.  How can I trouble shoot this, and/or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of trial and error it seems it was as simple as

changing  this...

```
documents do |doc|
 doc.attachments.each do |attachment|
  url = rails_blob_url(attachment, only_path: true)
  final_pdf << CombinePDF.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url)).body)
 end
end
```

to this...

```
documents do |doc|
 doc.attachments.each do |attachment|
  final_pdf << CombinePDF.parse(Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(attachment.url)).body)
 end
end
```

[url method docs](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob.html#method-i-url)